# Terminal: Selecting by MIME - need to ADD extension to each file

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal, automator

I have a LARGE number of old files and folders, MANY without extensions.

I have combined Mac's Automator and this shell code to successfully print out a list of all the file paths of one file type within the given folder.

I just don't know how to add the approprate extension (eg. ".tif") to the filtered list of files.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    find "$f" -type f -exec file --no-pad --mime-type {} + 2>/dev/null \
    | awk '$NF == "image/tiff" {$NF=""; sub(": $", ""); print}'
done
```

If I add:

```
mv -- "$f" "${f%}.tif"
```

it merely adds ".tif" to EVERY file and folder. Not the filtered list.

How do I only change the files that were in the results of the "print"?

Thanks for any help you can give! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the command to the next line instead in the loop block, which just applies for all the files.

For your current logic, it should be added to the output of awk

```
for f in "$@"
do
    find "$f" -type f -exec file --no-pad --mime-type {} + 2>/dev/null \
    | awk '$NF == "image/tiff" {$NF=""; sub(": $", ""); print}' | xargs -I{} mv {} {}.tif
done
```

Though, I am not sure if the approach is very efficient.

Edited again by stellababy:

You can approach your problem in this way using a for loop.

```
for f in `find . -type f ! -name "*.*"`
do
    file_type=`file -b --mime-type $f`
    if [ "$file_type" = "image/jpeg" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.jpg
    elif [ "$file_type" = "image/png" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.png
    elif [ "$file_type" = "image/tiff" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.tif
    elif [ "$file_type" = "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.psd
    elif [ "$file_type" = "application/pdf" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.pdf
    elif [ "$file_type" = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.ppt
    elif [ "$file_type" = "application/x-quark-xpress-3" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.qxp
    elif [ "$file_type" = "application/msword" ]; then 
        mv $f $f.doc
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try it ASAP. 

Comment: This was VERY helpful. It works on a small scale, ie. a few folders.

But if i apply it to a large folder (7GB) I get errors like:
"too many arguments (4885) -- limit is 4096"

Comment: "Couldn't posix_spawn: error 7"

Any ideas to fix these?

Comment: Brilliant help Black Pearl! Almost there now. Your new code is much easier to follow, so I edited it to check for multiple file types in one pass. I will get rid of Automator. Can you show me how to select a folder and it's contents for this search?

Comment: I was so excited I forgot to test the new loop! Somehow it loops infinitely… I passed the files of one folder to it in Automator and 16 files and it just keeps going... any ideas?

Comment: Why no $@ in the for statement this time? I’m trying to make sense of the loop (I’m a beginner with some very basic knowledge).

Comment: Oh, you can use "$@" if you call the function that way. Couldn't actually say without seeing the full code. I was just testing out with my files. Anyway that shouldn't loop infinitely. Add the full code here and have an echo in your loop and post the output. Might be able to help further.